# How to handle USB Drive mounting error

Tags: mount, usb-drive

I have a Monster Digital Overdrive USB SSD 128GB hard drive. I had it mounted and was copying files to it when my system shutdown for some reason. Now when I try and access it I get this error:

```
**Unable to access "OD ADVANCE"**

Error mounting /dev/sdb1 at /media/user/OD ADVANCE: Command-line 
`mount -t "exfat" -o
"uhelper=udisks2,nodev,nosuid,uid=1000,gid=1000,iocharset=utf8,namecase=0,err
ors=remount-ro,umask=0077" "/dev/sdb1" "/media/user/OD ADVANCE"' exited with
non-zero exit status 1:
stdout: `FUSE exfat 1.0.1'

stderr: `ERROR: `MD_Encrypt_User_Guide_v1.1.pdf' has invalid checksum (0xfdfb != 0xfde3).
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I extracted the following paragraph from an edit to the question by the OP, which should have been an answer instead.

> I can now use the drive. I tried to use it in Windows 8.1 and it said something was wrong with it. It repaired it and now I can use it in Ubuntu. Windows 8.1 appears to have deleted the pdf User Guide mentioned above (which came with the drive and was never used), as well as the encryption software that it applied to.

Comment: @Scooter Please accept this answer to mark your question as solved or write an answer and accept it yourself. Also note for the future that it is not appreciated if you edit your question to answer your own question. The question part of a thread is, well, for the question only. Answers should be always posted as answers. Thanks.